# Fill in a form on a site with information that was saved beforehand?

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-chrome-extension

so I'm working on an extension for Google Chrome for a friend. He wants it to fill out his shipping information when a checkout page is loaded with information filled out in a form beforehand. I've set up the form, and saved his information with the chrome.storage API. I can also track the URL that he is on with the tab API. The only thing I can't figure out is how to access the input fields of the page since it isn't my code. I can inspect the element and see the ID's, but since their page isn't linked to my JavaScript, I don't know how to get the strings in there. I've seen it done, and with this site too, but I can't find exactly how to do it. Can anyone nudge me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

*A nudge, you say.*

First, take a look at the [Architecture Overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch).

That will give you a hint that you need [Content Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) to interact with pages.

Then you may realize that you don't need to track tabs with `tabs` API - most likely just setting up a content script rule in the manifest is enough.

That should be enough for a nudge.

Comment: Thanks man, I'll take a look at it tonight and try to get it working!

Comment: So, I played around with it for a little bit and still can't get it working quite right. I put an alert message at the top of my js file saying that it is connected. When I go to the URL specified in the content_script section of my manifest.json, nothing happens. I don't think it is being injected, but I can't figure out why.

Comment: That would be a different question. But before you ask a new question, did you reload the extension after modifying the manifest?

Comment: Yup. I've been doing that every time I make a change.

Comment: Okay, I got it to execute the needed code when it reaches the certain url, but it can't access the ids of the input forms still. Everytime it tries to, I get "Cannot set property 'value' of null".

Comment: This is not a good place to ask. You may have more luck if you make a new question, with relevant code

Comment: Okay. I appreciate your help, Xan